# unable to display list of items with Nativescript-Vue GridLayout

Tags: nativescript-vue

Nativescript-vue newbie here...

I am using **nativescript-vue** to display a list of items. When the .vue page loads, the grid should just be an empty table.  When a button is clicked, the grid is populated with sub-elements of a list I retrieved from a service.  I am running into two issues:

1. There is only one row, where there should be a row per item in the list.
2. The date will be a date element such as `06-01-2019 11:30:01` but I would prefer to display it as `06-01-2019`

In my *.vue:

```
 <RadListView for="item in itemList" layout="grid" @itemTap="onItemTap">
   <v-template>
       <GridLayout rows="20, 20" class="list-item list-item-grid">
           <GridLayout row="1" rows="25, 35" columns="auto, auto, auto, auto">
             <Label col="0" :text="item.date" class="list-item-left" textWrap="true"verticalAlignment="middle" horizontalAlignment="left"></Label>
              ....
           </GridLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </v-template>
 </RadListView>
....
<script>
  expot default {

        data() {
            return {               
                itemList: []
            };
        },
        methods: { 
           getItems() {
             // really simplified but it will return something like:
              // [{"date" :"09-01-2019 11:32:01", "name":" first last"}]
            service.getItemArray()
           }
        },
         beforeMount: function() {
            this.itemList= this.getItems();
         }
</script>
```

I have put a shortened Playground version [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=DZuxlK):

Comment: yes, I have a console output that shows the empty array that gets assigned to itemList.  I think the original error I was worrying about is a known issue: https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/issues/529

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `v-if` to render the RadListView after the button is clicked, or manual [load on demand](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/professional-ui-components/ListView/load-on-demand).